# Find all strings in text file fitting either of two formats

Tags: python, string, text-files

So I know similar questions have been asked before, but every method I have tried is not working...

Here is the ask: I have a text file (which is a log file) that I am parsing for any occurrence of "app.task2". The following are the 2 scenarios that can occur (As they appear in the text file, independent of my code):

Scenario 1:

```
    Mar 23 10:28:24 dasd[116] <Notice>: app.task2.refresh:556A2D:[
    {name: ApplicationPolicy, policyWeight: 50.000, response: {Decision: Can Proceed, Score: 0.45}}
 ] sumScores:68.785000, denominator:96.410000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.713463}
```

Scenario 2:

```
Mar 23 10:35:56 dasd[116] <Notice>: 'app.task2.refresh:C6C2FE' CurrentScore: 0.636967, ThresholdScore: 0.410015 DecisionToRun:1
```

The problem I am facing is that my current code below, I am not getting the entire log entry for the first case, and it is only pulling the first line in the log, not the remainder of the log entry, and it appears to be stopping at the new line escape character, which is occurring after ":[".

My Code:

```
all = []
with open(path_to_log) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "app.task2" in line:
            all.append(line)
print all
```

How can I get the entire log entry for the first case? I tried stripping escape characters with no luck. From here I should be able to parse the list of results returned for what I truly need, but this will help! ty!

**OF NOTE: I need to be able to locate these types of log entries (which will then give us either scenario 1 or scenario 2) by the string "app.task2". So this needs to be incorporated, like in my example...**

Comment: Use f.readlines()

Comment: What actually constitutes an entry in the log? Can an entry span multiple rows?

Comment: I've read this somewhere, but had no luck implementing it. Is that supposed to allow me to read the next few lines of text?

Comment: Yes @norie, as you can see in the first instance, there are 3 lines

Comment: I edited heavily with better info

Comment: If the line matching `app.task2` ends with `]`, keep reading until you find the matching `]` line and include that in the log entry that you append.

Comment: correct, but how do I implement this 'keep reading'? That is what I am after!!! And actually, I want to keep reading beyond that...there is still more info I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before adding the line to `all`, check if it ends with `[`. If it does, keep reading and merge the lines until you get to `]`.

```
import re

all = []
with open(path_to_log) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "app.task2" in line:
            if re.search(r'\[\s*$', line): # start of multiline log message
                for line2 in f:
                    line += line2
                    if re.search(r'^\s*\]', line2): # end of multiline log message
                        break
            all.append(line)
print(all)
```

Comment: Still just returning: "Mar 23 11:19:23 dasd[116] <Notice>: bgRefresh-com.synchronoss.cloud.inbox-notifications:DC88CE:[" ... Not the few lines after that...hmmmm

Comment: Is there any whitespace after `[`? My code assumes it's the last character of the line.

Comment: Yes I suppose there is, after "[" the entire line is blank white-space until the new line starts, like I showed above.

Comment: I don't see any blank spaces between the `[` and the newline in your paste above.

Comment: Stupid, I forgot about the newline.

Comment: in your edited version, I am getting way more lines than I need when scenario 1 occurs. But I like how its handling it all in one entry in the list...how can we get it to stop after getting the 3rd line?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Now I see there's a space before `]`.

Comment: Its only supposed to reach the next few lines until a line contains ], but right not it is printing wayyy more rows than that.

Comment: I was checking `line` instead of `line2` inside the second loop.

Comment: I know what it's supposed to do, I just had some bugs.

Comment: Wow, I *never*  would have used nested `for` loops on the same file like that.  Good Trick!  I keep learning new things about iterators and generators versus lists and tuples!

Comment: I agree it's not intuitive, because you think of it like iterating over a list, and the inner loop looks like it's starting over. But using an iterator is more like a `while` loop that gets the next element.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over each each line individually which is why you only get the first line in scenario 1.

Either you can add a counter like this:

```py
all = []
count = -1
with open(path_to_log) as f:
    for line in f:
        if count > 0:
           all.append(line)
           if count == 1:
             tmp = all[-count:]
             del all[-count:]
             all.append("\n".join(tmp))
           count -= 1
           continue
        if "app.task2" in line:
            all.append(line)
            if line.endswith('[\n'):
              count = 3
print all
```

In this case i think Barmar solution would work just as good.

Or you can (preferably) when storing the log file have some distinct delimiter between each log entry and just split the log file by this delimiter.

Comment: Seeing the same as above...not getting that entire first entry still.

Comment: The exact format might not be correct, maybe ```if line.endswith('[\n')``` works?

Comment: otherwise, you can try: ```if line.rstrip().endswith('[')``` (removes the trailing whitespaces)

Comment: BINGO! the first one worked! THANKS! going to try it out more and confirm again

Comment: Spoke too soon, the last line is not found..."] sumScores:68.785000, denominator:96.410000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.713463}"...

Comment: try with ```count = 3```

Comment: Solved it! Now last thing!!! -- How can I get the those 3 lines returned as a single entry in the list I am making? right now they are separate...

Comment: you could check inside the ```ìf count > 0``` if the counter is 0 and if so concatenate the previous elements with something like ```"\n".join(line[-3:])```

Comment: I can edit my post if you want it more explicit

Comment: Ok, edited the post now. Basically, you just want to delete the last three elements and replace it with one concatenated element.

Comment: ```"\n".join(tmp)``` concatenates the elements with ```\n``` as the separator.

Comment: hmm still separate...any idea?

Comment: oh, it should probably be ```if count == 1```

Answer (score 1):

I like @Barmar's solution with nested loops on the same file object, and may use that technique in the future.  But prior to seeing I would have done it with a single loop, which may or may not be more readable:

```
all = []
keep = False

for line in open(path_to_log,"rt"):
    if "app.task2" in line:
        all.append(line)
        keep = line.rstrip().endswith("[")
    elif keep:
        all.append(line)
        keep = not line.lstrip().startswith("]")

print (all)
```

or, you can print it nicer with:

```
print(*all,sep='\n')
```